# If $G = PSL(2, p^n)$ with $p \ne 2$, then $C_G(R) = R$ for every subgroup $R \cong C_2 \times C_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, finite-groups

Consider $G = PSL(2, q)$ with $q = p^n$, i.e. the projective special linear group over a finite field of order $q$. Then $G$ could be considered as the group of all mappings
$$ 
 x \mapsto \frac{ax + b}{cx + d}
$$
on $\mathbb F_q \cup \{\infty\}$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb F_q$ such that $ad - bc$ is a square in $\mathbb F_q$. We have 
$$
 |G| = \frac{(q+1)q(q-1)}{k} 
$$
with $k = \operatorname{ggT}(2, q - 1)$. For the cyclic subgroup $U = \{ \alpha \in G : x^{\alpha} = a^2 x \mbox{ and } a \in \mathbb F_q^{\ast} \}$ we have 
$$
 |U| = \frac{q - 1}{k}
$$
and for each $\alpha \in U$ we have that $N_G(\langle x \rangle)$ is a dihedral group of order $2|U|$. Further it is possible to construct another cyclic group $S$ of order $|S| = (q+1)/k$ such that for $\beta \in S$ we have that $N_G(\langle \beta \rangle)$ is a dihedral group of order $2|S|$ (this is done with the help of a so called Singer cycle in $GL(2, q)$ and using the definition of $G$ as a factor group of a subgroup of $GL(2,q)$).

Further two distinct conjugates of the above subgroups $U$ (and also $S$) have trivial intersection. Further I know (I can supply the proof if wanted) that if $D$ is a dihedral group of order $4m$ and $R \le D$ is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$, then $C_D(R) = R$.

Now I am stuck on the following argument about subgroups of $G$ isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$.

> We either have $4m = q + 1$ or $4m = q - 1$, depending on which of both numbers is divisible by four. Set $Z := U$ if $q - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$, or $Z = S$ if $q + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. Then $N_G(Z)$ is a dihedral group of order $4m$ as written above.
>   Now suppose $R = \langle x, y \rangle \cong C_2 \times C_2$ with $x \in Z$ and $R \le N_G(Z)$. Suppose $x^g = x \in Z \cap Z^g$, as $Z \ne Z^g$ would imply $Z \cap Z^g = 1$, we must have $g \in N_G(Z)$. Further with the above mentioned fact about dihedral groups of order $4m$ we have
>   $$
>  g \in N_G(Z) \cap C_G(R) = R.
> $$
>   Hence $N_G(R) / R = N_G(R) / C_G(R)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the automorphism group of $R$. This implies that $|N_G(R) : R|$ is a divisor of $6$.

I see everything except why we have $N_G(R) / R = N_G(R) / C_G(R)$; I do not see how this is implied by what is written before? And also why does this implies that $R = C_G(R)$? So could anyone please help and clarify? Thanks!

Comment: Presumably $g$ is an element of $C_G(R)?$. Then $C_G(R)=R$ follows directly from the displayed equation.

Comment: Oh now I see it. If $h \in C_G(R)$, then in particular $x^h = x$, which shows by the computations $h \in R$ and the rest follows.